# How could I make sure that at least one DIV is always shown?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this piece of code I found that will show or hide a DIV using javascript. It only allows one div to be shown which is what I want. However, I want it where at least one DIV is always shown at a time. It basically toggles between hiding and showing them currently. I want it to be where if i hit DIV two again, it wont hide it and it will do nothing.
Please help, thank you.

page.html

```
    <script src="scripts/pages.js"></script>
    <div class="main_div">
        <div class="inner_div">
            <div id="Div1">I'm Div One</div>
            <div id="Div2" style="display: none;">I'm Div Two</div>
            <div id="Div3" style="display: none;">I'm Div Three</div>
            <div id="Div4" style="display: none;">I'm Div Four</div>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <a href="#" onclick="divVisibility('Div1');">Div1</a> | 
            <a href="#" onclick="divVisibility('Div2');">Div2</a> | 
            <a href="#" onclick="divVisibility('Div3');">Div3</a> | 
            <a href="#" onclick="divVisibility('Div4');">Div4</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

pages.js

```
var divs = ["Div1", "Div2", "Div3", "Div4"];
var visibleDivId = null;
function divVisibility(divId) {
  if(visibleDivId === divId) {
    visibleDivId = null;
  } else {
    visibleDivId = divId;
  }
  hideNonVisibleDivs();
}
function hideNonVisibleDivs() {
  var i, divId, div;
  for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divId = divs[i];
    div = document.getElementById(divId);
    if(visibleDivId === divId) {
      div.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code to following. Where you **hide all the divs** and show the div corresponding to the clicked element.

```js
function divVisibility(divId) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".inner_div > div").forEach(e => e.style.display = 'none');
  document.getElementById(divId).style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<div class="main_div">
  <div class="inner_div">
    <div id="Div1">I'm Div One</div>
    <div id="Div2" style="display: none;">I'm Div Two</div>
    <div id="Div3" style="display: none;">I'm Div Three</div>
    <div id="Div4" style="display: none;">I'm Div Four</div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <a href="#" onclick="divVisibility('Div1');">Div1</a> |
    <a href="#" onclick="divVisibility('Div2');">Div2</a> |
    <a href="#" onclick="divVisibility('Div3');">Div3</a> |
    <a href="#" onclick="divVisibility('Div4');">Div4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The part that causes this function to hide a div is the setting of visibleDivId to null.

```
function divVisibility(divId) {
  if(visibleDivId === divId) {
    // visibleDivId = null;
  } else {
    visibleDivId = divId;
  }
  hideNonVisibleDivs();
}
```

Commenting that line out (see line 3) keeps the clicked div as the visibleDivId and the second function (hideNonVisibleDivs) won't hide it.